# Configuring Subversion to use system users/passwords

Tags: svn, apache, webdav

I'm using [Subversion 1.6.1 with Apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic), on a Linux machine. The server is running over http, not https.

I want to allow people to authenticate using the same login/password that they use to log into the machine via SSH. The SVN manual only explains how to use HTTP Basic Auth and Digest authentication. But with these approaches, I need to maintain a separate list of users, and they can't change their own passwords. I'd prefer to just use the system's users.

1. How do I do this?
2. Is this wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question mentions basic/digest auth. First, note that basic/digest auth refers to the protocol between server and browser to communicate the user/password (on Apache 2.2, using authentication front-end modules such as **mod_auth_digest** and **mod_auth_basic**).

Behind the scenes, Apache can use a number of different sources of user/password information to check against. **mod_authn_file** which uses a "password file" is a common one, and it sounds as though that's what you're referring to.

To access the system user/password on a Linux box, Apache project itself doesn't provide any authentication back-end modules, but there are 3rd-party ones available. See this article which may be helpful:

[Apache 2.2 authentication with **mod_authnz_external**](http://blog.innerewut.de/2007/6/26/apache-2-2-authentication-with-mod_authnz_external)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...that's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is a perfect serverfault question.

BUT, I do it using WebDav in Apache and pwauth.

Comment: Likewise, but with mod_auth_shadow.

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason not to just access it via svn + ssh, since they have accounts?

Comment: HTTP may be preferable if access via the Internet is a requirement (SSH is blocked by many corporate firewalls, such as at my work).

Comment: Craig:  sure, that's why I asked if there was a particular reason for this, rather than just stating this was the way to do it.  svn+ssh is the easy way in this situation if it will work, but it won't work on every network.

Answer (score 1):

We have authentication against a windows domain set up with [`mod_auth_sspi`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/). No problems so far.

Comment: mod_auth_sspi wouldn't work on a Linux box, would it? I thought that was a Windows-only solution.

Comment: Apparently it can also be used on linux: http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-03/0931.shtml